# Ant scripts. Get disk free space during build

Tags: unix, ant, space, disk

We have a fairly complex system that runs multiple ANT builds simultaneously on a number of *nix PCs. We think that there are times when the disks fill up just before the clean up scripts run and/or the load on the PC is sufficiently high to cause issues when connecting to external servers (signing servers etc).

What we want is every 2 minutes to log the output of something like this to a file :

```
df . --direct -P --block-size=1m | tail -n 1 | awk {'printf("Free %dMb (%d%% Full)\t", $4, $5)'}; uptime
```

Is this possible in ANT (or ANT-contrib) or will I have to execute an external script?

My best solution so far is:

```
<target name="my_target">
    <parallel>
        <exec ... pc_status_every_2_mins_logger.sh />
        <sequential>
             ... rest of very large ANT script ...
        </sequential>
    </parallel>
</target>
```

I think this is rather clumsy and hoped that ant might have a much cleaner way to deal with this kind of issue.

Comment: is ant really the tool to use for building "multiple * builds simultaneously on a number of *nix PCs"? Aren't there newer tools that focus on the coordination of tasks across servers? Good luck!

Comment: Please try https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds. It has some way to check resources at slave side.

Comment: Oh how I would love to use anything other than ANT for what we are doing. Sadly many years ago someone started with CruiseControl and then decided to extend the functionality into a full build, integration and test system. There's now 10+ years worth of scripts, 150Gb SQL DB and about a peta byte of data spread over 5 countries! Now we are stuck with it. Other newer projects do use Jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the other way around - means not checking how much space but checking if there is enough space - and use the [hasfreespace condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) (since Ant 1.7.0)